# How to view data in the same form with GUI

Tags: c#

> Create a Form to enter Inventory Items that will be saved to a file.  You will want to create a class to include Item Code, Description and Price.  Use a button on the form to Add/Save the entered item to your file. Which will also clear the text boxes on the form when the add is competed.  This will make it ready to add the next item.  Include another button on your form, that when pressed will display all of the items in the file (that you added) on your form.

That the topic I need to do. I tried a couple of methods but it always crashed or gave me a message that my file was being used. Can you guys tell me what I need to do to fix this?

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    const string DELIM = ", ";
    const string FILENAME = @"C:\Users\Duckie\Desktop\C# Practice\Chapter.04\Quiz4\Inventory.txt";
    int code;
    string description;
    double price;
    static FileStream outFile = new
        FileStream(FILENAME,FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outFile);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        code = Convert.ToInt32(codeBox.Text);
        description = descriptionBox.Text;
        price = Convert.ToDouble(priceBox.Text);
        writer.WriteLine(code + DELIM + description + DELIM + price);
        codeBox.Clear();
        descriptionBox.Clear();
        priceBox.Clear();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: some times the exception does not tell the complete issue, it could be that you have permission issues writing to this directory or even the directory does not exist, change the path to something simple like "c:\" and see solves the problem.

Comment: one other thing, try not to use special characters in your path with spaces in the directory name, such as "C# Practice".

Comment: so i should use @"C:\Inventory.txt?

Comment: sure, if that solves the issue, then it is a path problem, then change the code to make sure the directory exists if not create it, then you know that you have permission to write to the directory.

Comment: @Dan you are doing a couple of things wrong here also 
`static FileStream outFile = new
 FileStream(FILENAME,FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write);
 StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outFile);` put his code inside of a method use  the free tools that are at your disposal like Google.. look up how to use `SaveFileDialog and OpenFileDialog` there are tons of working examples online to depict how to use them

Comment: The thing is I can't go beyond this book Microsoft Visual C# 2012 An Introduction to Object-Oriented Programming by Joyce Farrell.

Comment: Beside this is my first time learn about code too...

Comment: @dan first time or not. .don't just write code without reading , understanding , and knowing how to debug your code.. beginner or not.. there are plenty of free resources besides buying a book.. the internet has tons of basic C# tutorials for beginners as well as plenty of excellent sites that deal with Oriented Programming....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, use SaveFileDialog to open a file. And use OpenFileDialog to open a file when you want to show all inventory items in a list or table. Then you don't need to have the full path of the file in a string variable. What happens if you move the file into another directory?

Okay here is some code for saving into a text file and then reading it. Basically what the code does it that it saves a name you type in a textbox. Only requirement is that the file already exists(I have only used OpenFileDialog).
The class that saves and read from a file:

```
class SaveToFile
{
    static List<string> nameList = new List<string>();
    public static void Save(string filePath, string input)
    {   ///true only says that it is okay to append new lines into the file
        using (StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
        {
            sWriter.WriteLine(input);
        }
    }

    public static List<string> Read(string filePath)
    {
        string line = string.Empty;
        nameList.Clear();
        using (StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            while ((line = sReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            { 
                //I populate the list with the lines in the file
                nameList.Add(line);
            }
        }
        return nameList;
    }
 }
```

//and the view

```
public partial class SaveReadForm: Form
    {
        private OpenFileDialog opnFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        Person p = new Person();
        public SaveReadForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            opnFileDialog.Filter = "Text File[.txt]|*.txt";

        }

        private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (opnFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input.Text))
                {
                    p.Name = input.Text;
                    SaveToFile.Save(opnFileDialog.FileName, p.Name);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Add your name", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
        }

        private void readBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (opnFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                nameLstBox.Items.Clear();
                foreach (string s in SaveToFile.Read(opnFileDialog.FileName))
                {
                    nameLstBox.Items.Add(s);
                }
            }
        }
```

I hope this will help you understand how to write into and read a file.

Comment: I'm still new to C#. This is my first time touching all this coding and I still don't get some part of it. Can you show me some example?

Comment: Yes I'll be right back.

Comment: Thanks for the help....If something that similar to the topic I need to code will be great.

Comment: Thanks for the help....it's very clear how to do it...

Comment: so my code from above is no use at all? or i can still use it as my save button?

Comment: @dan you can still use your save button event but not the streamwriter inside it.